# Making a 6x6 grid with a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, grid, 2d, setw

this is what I have so far and I get an error: `setw` was not declared in this scope

```
void grid (void)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
        {
            cout << "-------------" << endl;
            cout << "|" << setw(4) << r + 1 << setw(4) << "|" << endl;
            cout << "-------------" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "-------------------------------";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setw` is defined in `iomanip` not `iostream`. Therefore add this line to your source file:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Comment: i realized that and added it, however, the grid still isnt printing the way it should. is there anyway i can send a picture of how it should look?